# Image float problems with Internet Explorer < 8

Tags: css, css-float, image

I've noticed a very annoying problem with the "float" css attribute and Internet Explorer 6 & 7.

I have an html with 2 simple images:

```
<img src="aa.jpg">
<img src="bb.jpg" class="alignright">
```

Here is the (very simple) CSS:

```
.alignright { float: right;}
```

With explorer the first image (without any float attribute):
http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2505/schermata4t.png

Is there any way to fix this problem with CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Place things you want to float at the right side of the container first (eq. the 'bb.jpg' image before 'aa.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more to do with the fact that you aren't floating your first image left too though.

check out http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/KUnNn/3/ for a detail of this.

This appears to happen in FF for me too, rather than just <IE8 as you suggested, so it would seem to be expected beahviour I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For IE7 / IE6 you have to...

- float the first image left
- float the second image right (or left also)
- add "clear:both" to the following text block (if you want it to appear after the images)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyq5u/

I used spans to simulate images.

CSS...

```
.img-a {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.img-b {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 100px;
    float: right;
}
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML...

```
<span class="img-a"></span>
<span class="img-b"></span>

<p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu  dolor et arcu dapibus cursus.
</p>
```